# Calculating NPV for future cash inflows

Tags: investing, business, financing, discounting

I have a question, where I am calculating the net present value of a project we are considering if it is beneficial or not. The project starts and the sales (cash inflows), don't start until a few years in. ie. there is several years of R&D before inflows are made. For example:

Project start date: Nov 2017, outlay of $55Million

First Sale (cash inflow): July 2019 - $54 Million

When calculating the NPV, is there anything I need to do in between the project start date outlay (Nov 2017), and the first cash inflow (July 2019). Do I need to discount the cashflow to the present, and if so, how?

Comment: I'd think of it as a "loan" where your customers don't make any payments (aka  sales/cash inflow) for the first 18 months, even though interest is still accumulating during those 19 months.  Of course that could be totally wrong.  Quantitative Finance.SE *might* be a better place to ask.

Comment: Actually, not a loan but an annuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When calculating the NPV, is there anything I need to do in between the project start date outlay (Nov 2017), and the first cash inflow (July 2019). Do I need to discount the cashflow to the present, and if so, how?

Yes, you need to discount *every* cash flow to the present time, not just the first one.

When discounting cash flows, the appropriate discount rate needs to represent the *opportunity cost* of the initial cash outlay.  Meaning if you were to use that money for something else, what rate of return would you expect?

You could be safe and assume only a risk-free return (like 2-3%) or use the average rate of return of other investments (e.g. 10-15%). Another common approach is to use your *cost of capital* if you're raising funds for the project, or would instead have use the funds to pay off existing debt.

Once you find a relevant discount rate, then just discount each cash flow by dividing them by `e^rt`, where `r` is the annualized discount rate (e.g. 0.10 for 10%) and `t` is the decimal number of years between now and the cash flow (e.g. 1.5 for 18 months)